Rocker panel guard paint — Why beige, not white?
I've seen a few paint brands that make black and beige rocker panel undercoating.
For example: Dominion Sure Seal - Rubberized Rockerguard Undercoating, Beige

What's the purpose of beige undercoating? It's not like the majority of vehicles are beige. If anything, there are more white vehicles, but not all paint companies make white undercoating.
My application is: Looking for a coating that can withstand stone chips and salt on rocker panels, on the bottom of doors, etc. (white truck).

Dirt and dust are more beige than white.
